# Ruby on Rails: Including multiple instance variables in partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So... I know about the `:locals => { :var1 => @rawr, :var2 => @hello }` syntax for partials
but is there a way for me to pass both `@rawr` and `@hello` to the partial, so that i don't need to use `var1` and `var2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `:locals => { :rawr => @rawr, :hello => @hello }` and then the variables will be available within the partial as `rawr` and `hello`.

Comment: but what if a want @rawr and @hello?

Comment: You can't have them. What's the problem with referring to `rawr` and `hello` in your partial?

Answer (score 1):

You know, you could just use @rawr and @hello ... and NOT pass any variables.

Comment: In that case, is there ever a reason to pass locals instead of just using the existing variables?

Comment: Yeah, if you dont have an instance variable already, or you might want to pass a variation on that instance variable, or loads of other reasons.

The key is to not set instance variables unnecessarily and use local variables wherever possible to avoid trampling of variable names.